# Why can't bash see my files?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, virtualenv

I have a simple bash script that allows `cron` to execute a series of Python scripts in a `virtualenv`. The script keeps raising `No such file or directory` errors.

`~/nightly.sh` works fine:

```
#!/bin/bash
source virt_env/myproject/bin/activate
cd virt_env/myproject/main
python script1.py
python script2.py
```

I want to keep everything in `~/virt_env/myproject/main/` to simplify deployment. I thought I could call `bash virt_env/myproject/main/nightly.sh` on this:

```
#!/bin/bash
MAINDIR=`dirname $0`
cd $MAINDIR
source ../bin/activate
python script1.py
python script2.py
```

but I get the `No such file or directory`. If I manually `cd` to `~/virt_env/myproject/main/`, then I can run the main commands no problem. Clearly I'm missing something about how `dirname` and `cd` work in this context.

How can I point bash at the right place?

## Solution

As proposed in the accepted answer, it's best to avoid calling `cd` from within the script and use an explicit path variable instead. Here's the working version of `virt_env/myproject/main/nightly.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
MAINDIR=`dirname $0`
echo "The main directory is" $MAINDIR

# Activate virtual environment
source $MAINDIR/../bin/activate

# Run Python scripts
python $MAINDIR/python1.py
python $MAINDIR/python2.py
```

Because the Python scripts are now called from an arbitrary path, I needed to update the python scripts to be smarter about path awareness as well.

This code fails because [`os.path.basename`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path#os.path.basename) omits path information:

```
# works when called with "python python1.py"
# fails when called with "python $MAINDIR/python1.py"
CONFIG_FILE = os.path.basename(__file__)[:-3] + ".config"
f = open(CONFIG_FILE,"r")
```

Updating it to use [`os.path.abspath`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path#os.path.abspath) fixes the problem:

```
# works regardless of how it is called
CONFIG_FILE = os.path.abspath(__file__)[:-3] + ".config"
f = open(CONFIG_FILE,"r")
```

Comment: whats the crontab entry?

Comment: I haven't brought crontab into the mix yet, I'm just launching the bash script from my home directory as crontab would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it would simply be better to eliminate the 'cd' command. Invoke everything from a full path specification. In your example add $MAINDIR/ to the executables.

Your bash script can then be in any directory where the executables are reachable. You are not exposed to the problems of what happens when cd fails.

Example:

```
cd yourdir
rm -f yourglob   # oops things got removed from where you started if yourdir did not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- Are you sure you know what the `dirname` command is doing? It's going to remove the top-level directory as well as the leading slash on whatever you call it on. I would make absolutely sure that the output of `dirname` is exactly what you think it is.

  For example,  `/home/user/` will output `/home`.
- You're using `~`, which references the `$HOME` variable in your environment. You didn't mention where the `cron` is listed, but make sure it's  not being run as a different user. Root's `~` and your `~` will be two completely different directories.

That's all I can think of. I hope that helps!

Comment: (ran out of edit time) Yes, `dirname` chops off the last argument, which I want because I'm calling a file. Thus `/path/to/file.txt` becomes `/path/to`. Using this to build an absolute path seems to work better. Chrontab of `7 14 9 10 * bash virt_env/myproject/main/nightly.sh` appears to work just fine with the new file.

Answer (score 0):

Add `echo $MAINDIR` after

```
MAINDIR=`dirname $0`
cd $MAINDIR
```

So you can see, if the contents of MAINDIR is correct.

Also you can run sh with `-x` or add `set -x` to the beginning of the script to see what happens.

Comment: `echo "MAINDIR is $MAINDIR"` yields `MAINDIR is virt_env/myproject/main`.